# JSData 3.0.0, AngularJS 1.x unit testing with $http mocks

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jsdata

I'm trying to figure out the current preferred way of unit testing modules which use js-data to gather data.

As I was starting to use jsdata I noticed that the adapter can take in a http method to use,  in the examples it shows the angularjs $http being used and I assumed (seemily incorrectly) that my existing test may actually work.  However, it doesn't appear to be and I'm finding most referring people to the js-data-mocks.

I want to verify that testing with the $http mocked is not going to work and perhaps why.

Also for js-data-mocks all the references don't appear to be using the 3.0 version of js-data and they seem to need js-data-angular which does not support 3.0

I'm assuming that I'm exploring this library in a transitional period.  It's a bit tough to know what is still applicable.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/78V11hccy8kdFIlfPpk0?p=preview for an example

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to also specify which promise library you use.
Shout out to Viktor Zozuliak on the jsdata slack channel for answering this.

This can be done like so:

```
.run(function($q) {
   window.JSData.utils.Promise = $q;
});
```